# IdentityServer3 TokenHandleStore

Tags: identityserver3

I have implemented IdentityServer3 within our web application. I use custom login with LocalRegistrationUserService and clients from db. It works great so far.

My next task is to store the access tokens to the database. I've looked at the IdentityServer3.EntityFramework source code (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework) and it looks quite a lot of things in there plus SQL tables.

My question is, do I need all of source code and the SQL tables? I just want to store the tokens and be able to load them. Also has anyone done it without using EntityFramework? If anyone has sample please share. Thank you.

ps: it's a pain that I have to convert this to VB

Comment: Why aren't you using the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework/) and [extension methods](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework/blob/252856d70d3762d5cc0127be2b747b50012500b5/Source/Core.EntityFramework/Extensions/IdentityServerServiceFactoryExtensions.cs) for configuration? The [WebHost](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework/tree/master/Source/WebHost) is a decent example of this.

Comment: Why do you need to store access tokens in the DB in IdentityServer? Do you mean reference tokens? Or are you saying you want to store access tokens in the client application database?

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the feedback.
Benjamin, thanks for the links. I'll check it out.

Brock Allen, the reason I want to store the access token in the database is because I see that there will problem when our website runs behind a balancing server. I've read a few threads where there is a little tweak to solve that problem, but I do not have the hardware or software to play with that.

I think using the custom TokenHandlestore will solve the server balancing issue and that is why I am looking at the EntityFramework sample from the URL above.

Comment: The identityserver is embedded within our website. If there are two web servers behind the balancing server, both web servers will run their own identitysever and accessing the same db.

The client request a token, serverA generates a token, stores in the DB and returns it to the client. When the client makes request, the balancing server redirects the call to serverB. ServerB retrieves the token from the db and parse/validate and executes whatever that request is. 
That is what i want to accomplish. Will it work? Yes my token type is Reference. Thank you

Comment: Benjamin, the entityframework sample is just over my head. :) ... it has the client, scope, consent, claim and all the goodies that I do not wish to touch. I am wondering if i can just do the TokenHandleStore. But I am not sure what files I need to convert. Our website is written in vb.net not c#.

Answer (score 2):

Based in your description, it appears you intent to keep your clients and scopes in memory but have all token and flow data persistent.

You will absolutely need more than just the TokenHandleStore to support the standard OIDC flows. Every operational store is essential except the ConsentStore. This one is optional only if your clients will never prompt users for scope consent. If you only want to support a subset of flow(s), you may be able to slip by with less, but it depends on the flows involved. For extensibility, posterity, and conformity, you probably want to have a fully-functional set of operational stores.

So, the options are to pull in the [IdentityServer3.EntityFramework package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework/) and use the [RegisterOperationalServices](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework/blob/master/Source/Core.EntityFramework/Extensions/IdentityServerServiceFactoryExtensions.cs#L25) extension method in your startup, or to write the operational stores yourself. Writing it all yourself would be somewhat beneficial as it provides some good insight into all of the OIDC flows. You are also not restricted to EntityFramework, and are free to choose your data access methodology.

I have written operational stores myself, excluding the ConsentStore. The schema is quite different from that in [IdentityServer3.EntityFramework](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework), but both serve the same purpose:

[image]

Comment: Benjamin, thank you for the table layout. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `ITokenHandleStore`. Implementing this interface will make you save tokens in your own database. Follow these steps below.

### Step 1. Get to know the interfaces in charge.

`ITokenHandleStore` itself doesn't have any signatures.

```
public interface ITokenHandleStore : ITransientDataRepository<Token>
{
}
```

`ITransientDataRepository<T>` has them instead.

```
public interface ITransientDataRepository<T> where T : ITokenMetadata
{
    //
    //     Retrieves all data for a subject identifier.
    //
    //   subject:
    //     The subject identifier.
    //
    //     A list of token metadata
    Task<IEnumerable<ITokenMetadata>> GetAllAsync(string subject);
    //
    //     Retrieves the data.
    //
    //   key:
    //     The key.
    Task<T> GetAsync(string key);
    //
    //     Removes the data.
    //
    //   key:
    //     The key.
    Task RemoveAsync(string key);
    //
    //     Revokes all data for a client and subject id combination.
    //
    //   subject:
    //     The subject.
    //
    //   client:
    //     The client.
    Task RevokeAsync(string subject, string client);
    //
    //     Stores the data.
    //
    //   key:
    //     The key.
    //
    //   value:
    //     The value.
    Task StoreAsync(string key, T value);
}
```

### Step 2. The interface overview.

This is the hierarchical relationship between the interfaces and implementations I've extracted from `VisualStudio`

[image]

### Step 3. Implementation for your own token storage.

All you need to do now is to create a class implementing `ITokenHandleStore` and tweak codes that access to your own database like this. ( this is a set of pseudo codes. )

```
public class HoanMadeTokenHandleStore : ITokenHandleStore
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ITokenMetadata>> GetAllAsync(string subject)
    {
        #region pseudo code
        // 1. Connect to database
        var db = Connection.connectDatabase("yourDatabaseConnectionString");

        // 2. Select tokens
        db.Query("SELECT * FROM Tokens");
        db.AddWhereCondition("SubjectId", subject);

        // 3. Actual Database Querying
        // SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE SubjectId = subject
        var results = db.Select();
        #endregion

        return results.Cast<ITokenMetadata>();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync(string key)
    {
        #region pseudo code
        // 1. Connect to database
        var db = Connection.connectDatabase("yourDatabaseConnectionString");

        // 2. Select tokens
        db.Query("SELECT * FROM Tokens");
        db.AddWhereCondition("key", key);

        // 3. Actual Database Querying
        // SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE AccessToken = key
        var token = db.Select();
        #endregion
        return token;
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        #region pseudo code
        // 1. Connect to database
        var db = Connection.connectDatabase("yourDatabaseConnectionString");

        // 2. Delete tokens
        db.Query("DELETE FROM Tokens");
        db.AddWhereCondition("key", key);

        // 3. Actual Database Querying
        // DELETE FROM Tokens WHERE AccessToken = key
        var token = db.Delete();
        #endregion
    }

    public async Task RevokeAsync(string subject, string client)
    {
        #region pseudo code
        // 1. Connect to database
        var db = Connection.connectDatabase("yourDatabaseConnectionString");

        // 2. Delete tokens
        db.Query("DELETE FROM Tokens");
        db.AddWhereCondition("ClientId", client);
        db.AddWhereCondition("SubjectId", subject);

        // 3. Actual Database Querying
        // DELETE FROM Tokens WHERE ClientId = client AND SubjectId = subject
        var token = db.Delete();
        #endregion
    }

    public override async Task StoreAsync(string key, Token value)
    {
        #region pseudo code
        // 1. Connect to database
        var db = Connection.connectDatabase("yourDatabaseConnectionString");

        // 2. Add Token
        db.Query("INSERT INTO Tokens");
        db.AddValues("AccessToken", key);
        db.AddValues("TokenType", value.type);
        db.AddValues("LifeTime", value.LifeTime);
        // and so on~

        // 3. Insert a token
        // INSERT 항목은 정하기 나름입니다.
        // this is only an example, you can store any properties you want or you think you'd need in the future.
        // INSERT INTO Tokens ( AccessToken, TokenType, LifeTime ) VALUES ( "adasdfcbe66qsa123512312", 3, 3600 );
        db.Add();
        #endregion
    }
}
```

### Step 4. Last thing to do

`IdentityServer3` uses `Autofac` as its `IoC` container, which means you're going to have to register your own implementation, `HoanMadeTokenHandleStore`. You may have seen this code when you were working with `IdentityServer3`.

```
.
.
.
var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();
factory.UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get());
factory.UseInMemoryClients(Users.Get());
factory.UseInMemoryScopes(Users.Get());
.
.
.
```

Yes, this `factory` is you should look at this time. This is the literally a `factory` for processing the token and every tasks in `IdentityServer3` pipeline. Simply adding this after initializing the `factory` object will do.

```
factory.TokenHandleStore = new Registration<ITokenHandleStore, HoanMadeTokenHandleStore>();
```

Then the `autofac` will inject your implementation at runtime. You can write any database related code in your own implementation eg. `HoanMadeTokenHandleStore`. Entityframework, ADO.NET, Dapper.NET or explicit SqlConnection and Commands, whatever.